# Android, Need more blur with ScriptIntrinsicBlur

Tags: android

I am using a radius of 25 and while it is a little blurry I am looking for more. Is there any better way to get more blur besides running the script multiple times?

```
    RenderScript rs = RenderScript.create(this);
    Allocation input = Allocation.createFromBitmap(rs, b, Allocation.MipmapControl.MIPMAP_NONE, Allocation.USAGE_SCRIPT);
    Allocation output = Allocation.createTyped(rs, input.getType());
    ScriptIntrinsicBlur script = ScriptIntrinsicBlur.create(rs, Element.U8_4(rs));
    script.setRadius(radius);
    script.setInput(input);
    script.forEach(output);
    output.copyTo(b);
```